# Listing names of current services

Tags: for-loop

Im in the process of creating a batch script and and the first should list the names of all current running services using SC.

***I can run the command on it's own.***

```
sc query state= all | find "SERVICE_NAME"
```

***But when I add the command into a for /f loop I get no results back.***

```
for /f "tokens=2" %a in ('sc query state= all ^| find "SERVICE_NAME"') do ECHO %a
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I found a way.

Comment: You need to comment out the equal sign. sc query  state^= all ^| findstr SERVICE_NAME'